# using Gmock to call a member function

Tags: c++, googlemock

This is the first time I'm working with gmock and have this exemple of Mock class

```
class MockInterface : public ExpInterface
{
public:
    MockInterface() : ExpInterface() 
    {
        ON_CALL(*this, func(testing::_)).WillByDefault(testing::Invoke([this]() {
            // I need to fill the testVec with the vector passed as parameter to func
            return true; }));
    }
    MOCK_METHOD1(func, bool(const std::vector<int>&));

    ~MockInterface() = default;
private:
    std::vector<int> _testVec;
};
```

then I created an instance of MockInterface

```
auto mockInt = std::make_shared<MockInterface>();
```

when Calling `mockInt->func(vec);` I need that the _testVec be filled with the vector passed in parameter to the `func` function, how to do this kind of stuff with gMock ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `SaveArg` action instead:

```
ON_CALL(*this, func(::testing::_)).WillByDefault(
    ::testing::DoAll(
        ::testing::SaveArg<0>(&_testVec),
        ::testing::Return(false)));
```

If you want to call a member function, you can use a lambda or pointer-to-member syntax.

```
ON_CALL(*this, func(::testing::_)).WillByDefault(
    ::testing::Invoke(this, &MockInterface::foo);

ON_CALL(*this, func(::testing::_)).WillByDefault(
    ::testing::Invoke([this](const std::vector& arg){ return foo();});
```

Remember that `Invoke` will pass all the arguments that the mock received to the invoked function and it must return the same type as mock function. If you want it without args, use `InvokeWithoutArgs`.